# How can i display a specific tooltip in a line chart, but also display the tooltip when dragging in flutter?

Tags: flutter, fl-chart

I'm creating a line chart using **fl_chart** in flutter, but there are a few conditions.

1. The maximum and minimum values ​​should be displayed as tooltips in the line chart.
2. When dragging on the line chart, the tooltip should be displayed automatically.

I was making a chart while looking at example 5, but
The tooltip is not displayed when dragging because the handleBuiltInTouches of LineTouchData is set to false.

I want a chart similar to the following photo.

Thank you for your help.

I wanted to create a line chart that met the conditions, but I couldn't.
We would appreciate it if you could share your opinions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.